# Redirect IP to domain issue

Tags: ssl, redirect, server, dns, digital-ocean

I have following domain name air8kissen.de. When I type in that domain name in browser it gets redirected to its IP address 178.128.117.168. The problem is that I setup SSL for domain name and since IP dont have SSL it shows the warning sign. When I accept to risk visiting the website, it redirects me to my domain name.

I have setup all necessary CNAME and A records inside Digitalocean domain setup and have no idea why it shows the IP address first time I visit to domain.

What should I do to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: You need to find where the redirect from `https://air8kissen.de` to `https://178.128.117.168` happens, and change the configuration so that it does not happen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a DNS or SSL issue, You need to setup the Virtual Host for your domain at your webserver, and check any redirection rules placed at your webserver level.